# How to measure training time per batches during Deep Learning in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to measure training time per batches during Deep Learning in Tensorflow.
There are several ways to measure training time per epochs, but I cannot find how to measure training time per batches.

I tried Tensorboard, but I don't know how to add some kind of 'execution time' scalars in tensorboard callbacks.

And I also tried to override the function 'train_step' but it didn't work the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a keras custom callback. The code below will print out the time it takes to process each batch, the training accuracy for that batch and the loss for that batch

```
class batch_timer(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self  ):
        super(batch_timer, self).__init__()
        
    def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.start_time=time.time()    
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        stop_time=time.time()
        duration =stop_time-self.start_time
        acc=logs.get('accuracy')* 100  # get training accuracy 
        loss=logs.get('loss')
        msg='processing batch {0:6s}  duration= {1:12.4f}  accuracy= {2:8.3f}  loss: {3:8.5f}'.format(str(batch), duration,  acc, loss)
        print(msg )
```

Now you are going to get tons of data . When you run model.fit include

```
history=model.fit(etc.... ,verbose=0, callbacks=[batch_timer()]
```

I set verbose=0 because if you don't the printout gets a bit messy because model.fit
printing gets messed up by the callback printing